# Finding the frequency of restaurant order cancellations by time in five second intervals

Tags: python, pandas, time, frequency

My data set looks like the below:

| order_id | canceled_at | accepted_at | Delta |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-07-02 23:30:26 | 2021-07-02 23:29:21 | 0 days 00:01:05 |  |
| 2 | 2021-09-17 20:35:44 | 2021-09-17 20:35:33 | 0 days 00:00:11 |  |
| 3 | 2021-05-21 11:47:28 | 2021-05-21 11:37:19 | 0 days 00:10:09 |  |
| 4 | 2021-06-18 7:34:06 | 2021-06-18 7:31:08 | 0 days 00:02:58 |  |
| 5 | 2021-05-16 15:54:34 | 2021-05-16 15:53:43 | 0 days 00:00:51 |  |

Delta is from the time the customer canceled the order to the time they put in their order. My goal is to find the frequency of restaurant order cancellations by time in five second intervals as well as mode, median, mean. However, I attempted the below:

`df_new.resample('5S', on='Delta').count().head(5)`

My results were not ideal:

| Delta | order_id | canceled_at | accepted_at | Delta |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 days 00:00:01 | 656 | 656 | 656 | 656 |
| 0 days 00:00:06 | 1348 | 1348 | 1348 | 1348 |
| 0 days 00:00:11 | 3874 | 3874 | 3874 | 3874 |
| 0 days 00:00:16 | 3586 | 3586 | 3586 | 3586 |
| 0 days 00:00:21 | 2916 | 2916 | 2916 | 2916 |

I'm not sure what's happening and I was hoping maybe someone could help? Thanks so much in advance! I think the count is filling everything.

Ideally I would just want the 2 columns

1. Delta to be grouped every 5 seconds (the minimum Delta is 1 second so that looks right)
2. and the count of cancellations per 5 second intervals.

| 5 Second Intervals | Count of Cancellations |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 25 |  |  |  |
| 6 | 30 |  |  |  |
| 11 | 6 |  |  |  |
| ... |  |  |  |  |
| ... |  |  |  |  |
| 1 minute and 1 second | 32 |  |  |  |

Comment: Will you please add a sample dataframe containing your expected output?

Comment: Hi @richardec thanks for the helpful comment - I added that in!

Comment: Can you provide your input as DataFrame constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(((df['Delta'].dt.seconds - 1) // 5) * 5 + 1).value_counts().reset_index()
```

The maths converts each `Delta` into a group-label. The `//` takes the quotient of division of 5 so that `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5` seconds (after subtracted by `1`) all become group `0`. We then revert it back into seconds by `* 5 + 1`. `value_counts` does exactly the counting. `reset_index` gives you back a dataframe.