# How to get mean/mode/median by Time Intervals with Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set that looks like this:

| 5_second_groupings | canceled_orders_count |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 days 00:00:01 | 656 |  |  |  |
| 0 days 00:00:06 | 1348 |  |  |  |
| 0 days 00:00:11 | 3874 |  |  |  |
| 0 days 00:00:16 | 3586 |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |

I want to find the below:

1. What is the most comment time interval where people cancel their orders after placing order? Is it 5 seconds after the order?

2)What is the average interval where people cancel their order in? Do most people cancel their orders after 11 seconds of ordering or 16? What's the average?

I know I can use mode medium functions to find but it's not giving me what I need. It's just giving me mode of canceled_orders_count but I want to take into account the 5 second groupings as well.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow"). For us to help you, provide a minimal reproducible problem set containing sample input, expected output, actual output, and all relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. What you have provided falls short of this goal. See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your Q1, `df.set_index('5_second_groupings')['canceled_orders_count'].idxmax()` will find the maximum `'canceled_orders_count'` but return the corresponding index which is one of the `'5_second_groupings'`

For your Q2, your need the weighted average, meaning an average of `5_second_groupings` weighted by `canceled_orders_count`, which means `(df['5_second_groupings'].dt.seconds * df['canceled_orders_count']).sum() / df['canceled_orders_count'].sum()`, given that `df['5_second_groupings']` is a datetime object so that `dt.seconds` will work. Btw, the average would have been more accurate if you just take the average of your `Delta` column in your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71028220/finding-the-frequency-of-restaurant-order-cancellations-by-time-in-five-second-i). Your estimate here should be under-estimating because the grouping rounded the `Delta` value down.